# which version of eclipse for android development is light and stable?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have started android development recently and i'm working on eclipse but it is very slow, i think because of it's heavy appearance. Please suggest me a good version which is totally light, it may lack in appearance but performance must be good.

Comment: For android development use `Android Studio`

Comment: None. The Android tools for Eclipse have been officially deprecated in favor of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Why should you use eclipse when Android studio is available with more and better options! It does half of the things on its own that a developer had to manage with eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

None.

The Android tools (ADT) for Eclipse were [officially deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html) in 2015 in favor of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it 's deprecated, but if you really need to use Eclipe ,i advice you to use eclipse Juno , and ADT  Version: 23.0.7.2120684. i'm  actually using it, and it's working without problem,  for some old (and complicated) projects that i didn't migrate them yet to android studio!.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a nice computer and AndroidStudio!